# Receiving results from dialogs

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog

I am trying to get some data from a dialog in an MFC C++ dialog-based application. I ahev made this image to help you understand better my situation:

[image]

When the user clicks the `findWndBtn` in the left-side window, the right-side dialog appears by `dlg.DoModal()` function. After the user completes the fields in the right-side the dialog, the following code is executed:

```
HWND WindowHandle = FindWindow( WindowClass, WindowName );
CDialogEx::OnOk();
```

After the dialog exits, I want the `m_myWndHwnd` field to pe filled with the handle found by that dialog.

How can I do that?

Tell me please, If didn't said enough, for me to complete with the detail that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Have the second dialog post a message back to the first dialog, passing the result you want to store as an argument.
- Have the second dialog store the result in a class member variable, and have the caller retrieve it (via a member function or directly if you're OK with that) when the dialog returns.